# How to solve java.lang.NullPointerException error?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

When I run my Java program, it gives me an error on this line

`compiler.getTask(null, null, new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>(), null, null, compilationUnits);`

Error I am getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at AnotherClassLoader.loadClass(test.java:58)
    at test.main(test.java:30)
    at Main.main(Main.java:68)
```

Can you please tell me how can I solve this error?

Comment: Please include a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) if you want any help. We can't do much without a SSCCE. Thanks. Oh, and consider changing the title of your question to something a little more descriptive please.

Comment: The stacktrace gives you the exact line where the `NullPointerException`occurs. You just have to understand why you got that and fix it...

Comment: It is solved by **identifying the problem** and then **correcting the identified problem**. NPEs [should] only occur in the case of: `someNullExpression.someMember`. That is, the `null` value must be the *target* expression of a member/method for this exception to naturally occur. In the posted example there is only *one* expression that can meet this requirement. (Hint: what does the `compiler` variable evaluate to?)

Comment: Relax, guys. He is asking what a null pointer exception is.

Comment: @pst Since the exception is in "AnotherClassLoader.loadClass", doesn't that imply the null pointer is further downstream? If compiler was null it would just be a null pointer exception right there in main.

Comment: @Jeremy It's something on line 58 of test.java... I don't think a real classloader can throw an NPE out like that, but I'm not sure now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234008/java-lang-nullpointerexception-error-how-to-figure-out

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings("null")
 public void WelcomeToNPE_MethodLand() throws NullPointerException {

  Object NPE_Wisher = null;

  try {
   if (!"Java".equals(NPE_Wisher))
    System.out.println("Am I executed....? - User");

   if (NPE_Wisher.equals(null)) //Here NPE_Wisher object will call mrNPE_Obj
    System.out.println("Shall I good till here...!");

  } catch (NullPointerException mrNPE_Obj) {
   
   System.out.println("You already had understand me... - NullPointerException\n");
   throw mrNPE_Obj;
   
  }
 }`

Answer (score 83):

A NullPointerException means that one of the variables you are passing is null, but the code tries to use it like it is not.

For example, If I do this:

```
Integer myInteger = null;
int n = myInteger.intValue();
```

The code tries to grab the intValue of myInteger, but since it is null, it does not have one: a null pointer exception happens.

What this means is that your getTask method is expecting something that is not a null, but you are passing a null. Figure out what getTask needs and pass what it wants!

Answer (score 7):

This error occures when you try to refer to a null object instance. I can`t tell you what causes this error by your given information, but you can debug it easily in your IDE.
I strongly recommend you that use exception handling to avoid unexpected program behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Just a shot in the dark(since you did not share the `compiler` initialization code with us): the way you retrieve the `compiler` causes the issue. Point your JRE to be inside the JDK as unlike jdk, jre does not provide any tools hence, results in `NPE`.